# Using trainImplicit for a Recommendation system

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Lets say I have a database with users buying products(There are no ratings or something similar) and I want to recommend others products for them. I am using `ATL.trainImplicit` where the training data has the following format:

```
[Rating(user=2, product=23053, rating=1.0),
Rating(user=2, product=2078, rating=1.0),
Rating(user=3, product=23, rating=1.0)]
```

So all the ratings in the training dataset is always 1.

Is it normal that the predictions ratings gave min value `-0.6` and max rating `1.85`? I would expect something between 0 and 1.

Comment: Your users only bought products once? all of them once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is normal. The implicit version of ALS essentially tries to reconstruct a binary preference matrix `P` (rather than a matrix of explicit ratings, `R`). In this case, the "ratings" are treated as confidence levels - higher ratings equals higher confidence that the binary preference `p(ij)` should be reconstructed as `1` instead of `0`.

However, ALS essentially solves a (weighted) least squares regression problem to find the user and item factor matrices that reconstruct matrix `P`. So the predicted values are not guaranteed to be in the range [0, 1] (though in practice they are usually *close* to that range). It's enough to interpret the predictions as "opaque" values where higher values equate to greater likelihood that the user might purchase that product. That's enough for sorting recommended products by predicted score.

(Note item-item or user-user similarities are typically computed using cosine similarity between the factor vectors, so these scores will lie in [-1, 1]. That computation is not directly available in Spark but can be done yourself).